# pass id from database to open modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

Here is code in which all the coupon table data is displayed with get code button.  I can't get the trick to send selected coupon id to open a modal. Her is the code in which all the data is displayed successfully. Below is the code for modal in which i have to pass the coupon id.

**code** works perfect..

```
  <?php
 $q=mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id ");
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'],'http');
 ?>
 <div id="popular" class="tab-pane counties-pane active animated fadeIn">
 <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
 <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
  <div class="savings text-center">
  <div>
  <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
  <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
   </div> </div> </div>
  <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">
  <h4 class="coupon-title"><a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></a></h4>
   <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1">Shop these Shopname deals of the day to save as much...</p>
   <p id="1" class="collapse">Don't miss out on all the coupon savings.Get you coupon now and save big</p>
     </div>
    <div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">
    <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".couponModal">
    <span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span> 
    <span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></p>
    </div></div> </div>
      <?php
           }
       ?>
```

**Modal** It is on same page.

```
<?php
 // can't get the query for the selected coupon code to open this modAL
?>
  <div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span></button>
 <div class="coupon_modal_content">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
  <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
  <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
  </div><div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"><h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info"><span class="coupon_icon">
   <i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span> <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?> </a></div></div> </div></div>
                        <!-- end: Coupon modal content -->
  </div></div></div> </div> <!-- end: Modall --></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append the ID you want to transfer to the Coupon Modal Name.

```
<p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".couponModal_<?php echo $your_id; ?>">
```

Finally, in the Modal, use the below code.

```
<div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal_<?php echo $your_id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

Hope this works.

---

Since your data is being populated within a `while` loop of PHP, so you need to have your entire Modal Code within the loop.

Just to clarify, since your data is being populated from the DB, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to have `$your_id` encrypted in order to make it secure.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain this further. To have the ability to capture the different values of different records in Modal, you need to have different modals. This can easily be achieved by having your modal code within the PHP while loop and having the $your_id appended as explained earlier.

Comment: Beware using `class` to open modal

Comment: Getting the work done with proper education and getting work done without proper education are two different things. We use `IDs` to distinguish different things of same category. What if you have a course to study and there are 30 students. Would create 30 sections or just give unique IDs to all 30 students. Think about it mate

Comment: Please note that $your_id is actually $row['c_id']. I prefer to store the fetched value in a variable and then use.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi I also prefer that but that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit modification to Akhtar's answer. I would recommend using `ID`

```
<p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#couponModal_<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">
```

Finally, in the Modal, use the below code.

```
<div class="coupon_modal modal fade" id="couponModal_<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

//Whole code

```
<?php
 $q=mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id ");
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'],'http');
 ?>
<p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#couponModal_<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">
 <div id="popular" class="tab-pane counties-pane active animated fadeIn">
 <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
 <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
  <div class="savings text-center">
  <div>
  <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
  <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
   </div> </div> </div>
  <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">
  <h4 class="coupon-title"><a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></a></h4>
   <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1">Shop these Shopname deals of the day to save as much...</p>
   <p id="1" class="collapse">Don't miss out on all the coupon savings.Get you coupon now and save big</p>
     </div>
    <div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">
    <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".couponModal">
    <span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span> 
    <span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></p>
    </div></div> </div>

<div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="couponModal_<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span></button>
 <div class="coupon_modal_content">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
  <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
  <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
  </div><div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"><h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info"><span class="coupon_icon">
   <i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span> <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?> </a></div></div> </div></div>
                        <!-- end: Coupon modal content -->
  </div></div></div> </div> <!-- end: Modall --></div>
      <?php
           }
       ?>
```

Comment: This one is working but it is opening modal as faded screen.

Comment: this one is working for me but the modal is displaying faded still

Comment: Check your html